# aiogram получение message_id

Tags: python, aiogram

Как из reply_to_message получить message_id в aiogram

Answer (score 0):

Сохраняешь отправляемое сообщение в переменную, затем вызываешь метод message_id.

```
msg = await message.answer(text)
await bot.send_message(chat_id, text, reply_to_message_id=msg.message_id)
```

Атрибуты сообщения можно посмотреть через *dict*:

```
print(msg.__dict__)
```

---

```
@router.message(Command("start"))
async def cmd_start(message: Message, bot: Bot) -> None:
    msg = await message.answer("Hello, World!")
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Second Hello, World!", reply_to_message_id=msg.message_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, нужно получить id сообщения на который был ответ.

```
if msg.reply_to_message: #проверям, было ли сообщение написано с ответом на какое-то сообщение
   print(msg.reply_to_message.message_id) #выводим id сообщения, на который был ответ
```